# Prove product of projections is bounded

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

Let $P$ and $Q$ be two orthogonal projections (so that means they are linear, idempotent, and self adjoint) such that $P-Q$ is a compact operator (so that means the closure of $(P-Q)(B_1(0))$ is compact where $B_1(0)$ is the open unit ball around zero of radius $1$).

How do you show that $PQ$ is bounded?

I am a bit stuck about this because I'm not sure how to translate the compactness condition (which is weaker) into a bounded condition (which is stronger). I tried to think of: $$ ||PQ||\leq||P|| ||Q|| $$ and of $$ PQ=P+QP_{\perp}-(P-Q)^2 $$ But neither lead me to any fruitful directions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any orthogonal projection is bounded: for any $v$, $$\|v\|^2=\|Pv+P_\perp v\|^2=\|Pv\|^2+\|P_\perp v\|^2\geq \|Pv\|^2$$ (the second equality holding because $Pv$ and $P_\perp v$ are orthogonal), so $\|P\|\leq 1$.  Thus $PQ$ is a composition of bounded operators and hence bounded itself.

Answer (score 3):

$$ ||PQ||\leq||P|| ||Q||\leq 1.1=1$$

[Operator norm of orthogonal projection](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/798472/operator-norm-of-orthogonal-projection)