# Projections on Normed Spaces

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces, normed-spaces, projection

Let $\mathbb{E}$ be a (real or complex) Banach space (complete normed space). Let $P$ be a projection ($P^2=P$) from $\mathbb{E}$ into itself.

Is it necessarily that the norm of $P$ equals to $1$?

Comment: No. Try $P=\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 1 & 0 \end{bmatrix}$. Then $\|P\| = \sqrt{2}$.

Comment: A (nonzero) projection must have norm ${}\ge 1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not true in general (e.g. with $P=0$). However, if the projection is orthogonal and nonzero, then the norm is certainly $1$. See, for instance, [Operator norm of orthogonal projection](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/798472/operator-norm-of-orthogonal-projection).